# inject an html snippet with npm scripts on build

Tags: code-snippets, inject, npm-scripts

I have a `src` folder and a `public` folder. The `src` folder has many subfolders, each with an index.html. On `npm run build` each folder is copied from `src` to `public`.

I want to have an npm script that looks for every index.html file, and inserts an html snippet into the body, like a div with a logo.

I have netlify doing this right now but would like to incorporate it into my build step, and would also like to avoid using gulp. Any direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That should be quite simple, just write a script like 'npm run build && node addStuff', where addStuff is a javascript file which using the fs module reads the index.html files, parses where you want to insert the snippet, inserts it and rewrites the file.

Comment: so I got this working, https://repl.it/@ssccdd/lil-node-regex-injector, but how to I .. apply that to each index.html and have it copy out to public with the same hierarchy?

Comment: Well, I would do like so, something like console.log(fs.readdirSync("./", { withFileTypes: true })); will tell you the files local to where you execute it, you can put a proper path in as well. So write a function which looks in a directory, if it finds a index.html it applies the bit you wrote, and if it finds directories it recursively applies the function now looking in each directory. Regarding the hierarchy, my suggestion is that you let npm run build do the hierarchy and then just apply the above to the public folder.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I got this partially working, for my uses where I just need to read the `public` directory and one layer of sub directories. But, I can't seem to access subDirectories variable outside the `addSnippetToIndexes` fs function. Any ideas? I tried a callback below, no dice. I am a real node n00b.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const logo = '<div id="logo"><h1>my cool logo</h1></div>'
let subDirectories = []

function addSnippetToIndexes(directory){
    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}
        files.forEach(file => {
            if(file.substr(-5) === '.html'){
                fs.readFile(directory+file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
                    if (err) {return console.log(err);}
                    let result = data.replace(/\<\/body>/g, logo + '</body>');
                    fs.writeFile(directory+file, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
                       if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
                  });   
            }else{
                subDirectories.push(file)
            }
         });
         //I can access subDirectories here but not outside function?
    });
}
addSnippetToIndexes('./public/')
subDirectories.forEach(i => {addSnippetToIndexes(i)}) //THIS DOESNT WORK?
```